# Connect two toggle buttons to switch each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, toggle

I have two toggle switch buttons in which button 1 is checked as default. When clicking the 1st button, the 2nd button should be on and the 1st button should be off and after clicking the 2nd button 1st button should be on and the second button should close. Only one button can be on at one time.
I tried different methods but nothing works perfectly.

HTML code :

```
<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:2em; margin-left:-2em">
     <span class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="switch-id1" @click="" checked>
     </span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:2em; margin-left:-2em">
     <span class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="switch-id2" @click="" unchecked>
     </span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
$switch-height: calc(#{$input-height} * .8) !default;
$switch-height-sm: calc(#{$input-height-sm} * .8) !default;
$switch-height-lg: calc(#{$input-height-lg} * .8) !default;
$switch-border-radius: $switch-height !default;
$switch-bg: $custom-control-indicator-bg !default;
$switch-checked-bg: map-get($theme-colors, 'primary') !default;
$switch-unchecked-bg: map-get($theme-colors, 'primary') !default;
$switch-disabled-bg: $custom-control-indicator-disabled-bg !default;
$switch-disabled-color: $custom-control-description-disabled-color !default;
$switch-thumb-bg: $white !default;
$switch-thumb-border-radius: 50% !default;
$switch-thumb-padding: 2px !default;
$switch-focus-box-shadow: 0 0 0 $input-btn-focus-width rgba(map-get($theme-colors, 'primary'), .25);
$switch-transition: .2s all !default;

.switch {
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  position: relative;

  input {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    clip-path: inset(50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    + label {
      position: relative;
      min-width: calc(#{$switch-height} * 2);
      border-radius: $switch-border-radius;
      height: $switch-height;
      line-height: $switch-height;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      user-select: none;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-indent: calc(calc(#{$switch-height} * 2) + 3.5rem);
    }

    + label::before,
    + label::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: calc(#{$switch-height} * 2);
      bottom: 0;
      display: block;
    }

    + label::before {
      right: 0;
      background-color: $switch-bg;
      border-radius: $switch-border-radius;
      transition: $switch-transition;
    }

    + label::after {
      top: $switch-thumb-padding;
      left: $switch-thumb-padding;
      width: calc(#{$switch-height} - calc(#{$switch-thumb-padding} * 2));
      height: calc(#{$switch-height} - calc(#{$switch-thumb-padding} * 2));
      border-radius: $switch-thumb-border-radius;
      background-color: $switch-thumb-bg;
      transition: $switch-transition;
    }

    &:checked + label::before {
      background-color: $switch-checked-bg;
    }

    &:checked + label::after {
      margin-left: $switch-height;
    }

    &:focus + label::before {
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: $switch-focus-box-shadow;
    }

    &:disabled + label {
      color: $switch-disabled-color;
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }

    &:disabled + label::before {
      background-color: $switch-disabled-bg;
    }
  }

  // Small variation
  &.switch-sm {
    font-size: $font-size-sm;

    input {
      + label {
        min-width: calc(#{$switch-height-sm} * 2);
        height: $switch-height-sm;
        line-height: $switch-height-sm;
        text-indent: calc(calc(#{$switch-height-sm} * 2) + .5rem);
      }

      + label::before {
        width: calc(#{$switch-height-sm} * 2);
      }

      + label::after {
        width: calc(#{$switch-height-sm} - calc(#{$switch-thumb-padding} * 2));
        height: calc(#{$switch-height-sm} - calc(#{$switch-thumb-padding} * 2));
      }

      &:checked + label::after {
        margin-left: $switch-height-sm;
      }
    }
  }

  // Large variation
  &.switch-lg {
    font-size: $font-size-lg;

    input {
      + label {
        min-width: calc(#{$switch-height-lg} * 2);
        height: $switch-height-lg;
        line-height: $switch-height-lg;
        text-indent: calc(calc(#{$switch-height-lg} * 2) + .5rem);
      }

      + label::before {
        width: calc(#{$switch-height-lg} * 2);
      }

      + label::after {
        width: calc(#{$switch-height-lg} - calc(#{$switch-thumb-padding} * 2));
        height: calc(#{$switch-height-lg} - calc(#{$switch-thumb-padding} * 2));
      }

      &:checked + label::after {
        margin-left: $switch-height-lg;
      }
    }
  }

  + .switch {
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use checkboxes, don't use JS. Simply use two **radio buttons** with a same `name`  and a different `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with vue:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    status: true
  }),
  methods: {
    clicked(val) {
      this.status === val ? this.status = !val : this.status = val
      // some other stuff you need on click
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="demo">
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:2em; margin-left:2em">
     <span class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="switch-id1" @click="clicked(false)" :checked="status">
     </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:2em; margin-left:2em">
     <span class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="switch-id2" @click="clicked(true)" :checked="!status">
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tip for OP: from a User Experience point of view — would be always better to stick to the proper UI, and that's: two radio buttons. Win/win situation: no JS required at all.

Comment: Thanks, @Nikola Pavicevic. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @Ashwin Singhal you are welcome mate, cheers :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan first I used radio buttons but the requirement is of a toggle button.

Comment: @AshwinSinghal you can style a single checkbox to be shown as a "toggle button" with two states. You don't need TWO. One checkbox should be used. (If I understood you correctly).